# AVR Assembler check is number odd

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, bit, avr

So we gotta make a simple program that gonna check out is number odd or even.

That is my first time with assembler.
Many examples were about ARM and WASM, but its AVR is really pain.

```
start:
ldi r16, $0
ldi r17, $1 ; Load decimal 1 into r16
ldi r18, $2 ; Load decimal 2 into r17
ldi r19, $3 ; Load decimal 3 into r18
ldi r20, $4 ; Load decimal 4 into r19
ldi r21, $5 ; Load decimal 5 into r20

CLC                 ; clear carry flag
tst r21             ; check is r20 odd
BRHS    isodd       ; goto is odd
    MOV r10, r18    ; not odd
    JMP exit
isodd:
    MOV r10, r17    ; is odd
exit:
nop
```

Comment: Your `tst` opcode is checking for 0 or negative (zr or carry).  That won't capture odd/even.  Consider using something like `andi r21,1` and checking for zero flag on that.  You could also use a shift right (`lsr r21`) and check carry for odd as well.  These both affect the r21 register though so beware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AVR allows efficiently testing any single bit** by copying it into the T flag with [`bst`](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-73B216FB-3804-4FC9-BBDD-8F6F5F055D17.html) where you can branch on it.  (Or copy it to another bit of another register with `bld`, as shown in the manual's example for `bst`.)

The key instructions here:

- [`BST` – Bit Store from Bit in Register to T Flag in SREG](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-73B216FB-3804-4FC9-BBDD-8F6F5F055D17.html).
- [`BRTC` – Branch if the T Flag is Cleared](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-E53D1963-12BB-4806-9DB7-7A216DCA20D3.html)    (There's a corresponding `BRTS` for T==1)

```
   bst   r21, 0            ; T = (r21 >> 0) & 1
   brtc  is_even           ; jump if (r21 & (1<<0) == 0)
```

Or even better, if your branch only needs to skip *one* instruction, [`sbrs` - Skip if Bit in Register is Set](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-5C781785-0CB7-4A06-B213-80DE33FFED2F.html).  (The skipped instruction could itself be a branch, if you wanted, but bst / brt[sc] may be faster in that case.)

```
   sbrs r21, 0
     nop              ; runs only for even R21

   ... code that runs for both cases
```

e.g. GCC uses it when compiling `if(x&1) bar();` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s4MdE3)):

```
foo:
        sbrs r24,0
        ret             ; return (skipped for odd)
        rjmp bar        ; else tailcall
```

---

The manual says `tst reg` is just an alias for `and reg,reg` to set flags according to the whole value.  ([html extract](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-B44BD86E-5D63-4F9F-94E6-0C98CEA5D6A3.html)).

Unlike some ISAs with more opcodes (like ARM where you would `tst r0, #1`), AVR doesn't have a non-destructive AND-but-only-set-flags instruction, only a `cmp` (which is like sub but doesn't modify the destination reg).  If you wanted to do it that way, you could load a `1` into another register and AND into that, setting or clearing the Z flag for BRNE or BREQ.

Or `andi r21, 1` if you don't mind destroying r21.  Or right-shift it to shift the low bit into the carry flag.  This does still let you branch on odd/even in 2 instructions instead of 3, in a way that's more like other ISAs.

Comment: Always forget that godbolt can easily test things and compiler are better than developers who have not worked with this particular assembler before.  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Heh, yup, I thought I was doing pretty well to have found `bst` in the instruction set (like you I only know it from SO questions), then GCC showed me an even better way for the particular test-case I'd cooked up.

Answer (score 1):

Your tst opcode is checking for 0 or negative (zr or carry falg set). That won't capture odd/even. Consider using something like andi r21,1 and checking for zero flag on that. You could also use a shift right (lsr r21) and check carry for odd as well. These both affect the r21 register though so beware.

```
...
ldi  r21, $5   ; Load decimal 5 into r20
andi r21, $1   ; check is r20 odd
breq is_even   ; if zero flag is set, the low bit was clear.  Even.

mov  r10, r17  ; This is the Odd pass
jmp  exit

is_even:
mov  r10, r18  ; This is the Even pass
exit:
...
```

All opcode info pulled from http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf

Standard disclaimer - I can't test this code locally, but it demonstrates the technique I believe that you need.

Comment: Turns out AVR can non-destructively test a single bit in 2 instructions, just not arbitrary AND masks (which as you show are either destructive or would need the value in a scratch register to AND into).  Posted an answer.